# Why does this code for TcpClient work in vb.net, but not c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcpclient

A little experiment here, code that I inherited and plan to refactor, but I'm stumped on one thing. The one in `vb.net` works, but the one in `c#` does not.

By the way, `BUFFER_SIZE` is equal to **2048**, and I know it has several issues, but I can only assume I'm misunderstanding the correlation between `Byte` constructs with the two languages:

```
Dim bytesRcvd As Integer = 0
Dim byteSendBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {}
Dim byteReceiveBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {}
Dim receiveMessage As String = Nothing
byteSendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage)
Dim client As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient = Nothing
Dim netStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = Nothing

client = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("localhost", 9060)

netStream = client.GetStream()

netStream.Write(byteSendBuffer, 0, byteSendBuffer.Length)
bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteReceiveBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)
receiveMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd)
netStream.Close()
client.Close()
```

C#:

```
int bytesRcvd = 0;
var byteSendBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
var byteReceiveBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
string receiveMessage = null;
byteSendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage);
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = null;
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream netStream = null;
client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("localhost", 9060);

netStream = client.GetStream();

netStream.Write(byteSendBuffer, 0, byteSendBuffer.Length);
bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteReceiveBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

receiveMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
netStream.Close();
client.Close();
```

The error received is:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

This occurs on `netStream.read`

Ah yes, so `Byte` is handled differently.. Focusing on the c# version, changing:

```
var byteSendBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
var byteReceiveBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
```

To this:

```
var byteSendBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
var byteReceiveBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

No error, but `netStream.read` hangs indefinitely, so apparently not getting any data back, right?

I tried wrapping it all with:

```
if(netStream.CanRead()) { ... }
```

Didn't work, still hangs.

Can you spot a reason? Again, yes I'm aware that this is ugly. I'll get to that.

**Update**

This is absolutely frustrating. I've tried numerous examples of suggested configurations for this. In the new `c#` (or was) solution, I added a `vb` project just for TcpClient commands. No matter what else I do, it hangs indefinitely on `read`, but works with `vb`.

**Final Update**

Well, all of this hassle and helpful advice, and it turns this was one of those huge major coincidences dealing with small details, as in the listening service on the other end that I didn't have access to. The procedure to return the messages to be sent to the listener was returning incorrect messages, and the listener was not responding with data, and it just timed out. Such a tiny detail, (like a few characters) that it was hard to spot.

Comment: `New Byte[BUFFER_SIZE - 1]` equivalent to `new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]` in C#. Possibly a timeout occurred when executing `GetStream().Read()`?

Comment: As @TetsuyaYamamoto comment suggests, you need to specify the upper bound when creating an array in VB whereas C# requires the length, so the number should always be 1 greater in C#.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Thank you. Correct, as I changed the `BUFFER_SIZE` as shown in question. I'm completely at a loss as to why the `c#` is still not working. While would the `vb` version not time out? Has to be staring me in the face.

Comment: Nothing obvious here but some evidence of a common mistake - you're referring to *messages*, but TCP doesn't do *messaging*. There's no guarantee that your call to `Read` is going to receive a copy of a buffer that was passed to a single call to `Write` at the other end. TCP is just an endless stream of bytes, so any *particular* read call may receive (for instance) just a portion of one buffers worth of data written at the other end, or data that was provided in *multiple* calls to `Write` at the other end.

Comment: `NetworkStream.Read()` blocks ("hangs") until there is data available to read. If it never continues that means that the endpoint hasn't sent anything. If you want to determine whether there is data to read _before_ actually trying to read it, check: `if(netStream.DataAvailable) { ... }`.

Comment: The only difference I'm able to spot is one method is called from a traditional web forms submit, whereas on the new program, it's being called inside of a WebAPI controller class.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, please see my latest update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteReceiveBuffer, 0,
 byteReceiveBuffer.Length);
```

Instead of

```
bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteReceiveBuffer, 0,
     BUFFER_SIZE );
```

your byteReceiveBuffer length is  is 2047 and BUFFER_SIZE is 2048

Comment: While you answer is not technically wrong, what you are suggesting makes the C# code different to the original VB. The better solution is to make the array the correct size in the first place.

Comment: Thank you but this still doesn't solve the issue. It still hangs, and can't figure out why the `vb.net` version does not. As stated in another comment, probably staring me in the face.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, please see my latest update to the question.